# extjs combobox two columns

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I would like to display two columns in my combobox. I read in various forums, but everyone says to use the property tpl. but since I'm using sencha architect this property can not find it. a similar rendertpl but does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can add any new attribute that is not already in the list by typing it into the search box at the top of the property toolbox and then click the "Add" button to the right of the search box.  These can be custom attributes that you handle manually yourself or they can be built in attributes that Sencha just forgot to include in the attributes list (or left out for one reason or another).

--Stewart McGuire